# Python Auto-Click Program isn't Clicking on Button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, autofill

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/mymac/Documents/AutoFill/chromedriver")
browser.get("https://www.jcpenney.com/p/a-n-a-skinny-denim-ankle-crop-jeans/ppr5007199315?pTmplType=regular&catId=cat100250096&deptId=dept20000013&urlState=/g/womens-jeans/N-bwo3xD1nopgw&badge=onlyatjcp")

cart = browser.find_element_by_class_name('button')
time.sleep(5) 

cart.click()
```

This is basically adding an item to my cart ("cart" is the add-to-cart button). However, whenever I run this, I get an error on my last line:

error:     selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

Here is the HTML from the website:

HTML from Website; the highlighted blue portion refers to the button that I want to click

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you try using `cart = browser.find_element_by_name('commit')`

Comment: I get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"commit"}

Comment: if i see the link there is button "add to bag"  this is what you want to locate ?

Comment: Yes, the add to bag button on this link: http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/tops-sweaters/std3569zk/iewl6gphq

Comment: `browser.execute_script("document.querySelector('#cart-addf').submit()")`

Comment: `cart = browser.find_element_by_id('addtobag')` or  `cart = browser.find_element_by_name('add to bag')` let me know if still failing

Comment: The page url in your code is not same as the one in your above comment.  Please clarify which url is correct and update your code or comment. Don't make confusion.

Comment: See give us a clarity about your question there are two URLs

Answer (score 0):

see you have alert , sizerange,sizenumber, then after it click on the add to bag button and colour i kept defaut black colour

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
browser = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/mymac/Documents/AutoFill/chromedriver")
browser.maximize_window()
selectsizerange = input("Enter SIZE RANGE")
sizenumber = input("ENTER SIZE NUMBER")
browser.get("https://www.jcpenney.com/p/a-n-a-skinny-denim-ankle-crop-jeans/ppr5007199315?pTmplType=regular&catId=cat100250096&deptId=dept20000013&urlState=/g/womens-jeans/N-bwo3xD1nopgw&badge=onlyatjcp")
time.sleep(5)
browser.switch_to_active_element()
browser.find_element_by_id('closeButton').click()
time.sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_id('SIZE_RANGE').send_keys(selectsizerange)
browser.find_element_by_id('SIZE').send_keys(sizenumber)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ul#COLOR li:nth-child(1) > img").click()
time.sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.pp__cta__all > div:nth-child(1) > button").click()
```

Comment: if u want to know how to click on all colours like color selector ping me